# How can I compare a DATE value with the result of GETDATE()

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to grant and revoke server roles for user id picked from a table.

I am using the following query to insert a row from master table to another table whenever the expiry date approaches, however the command is not inserting any rows into the slave table.

```
Insert into tbl2(userid, role, startdate, expirydate)
Select userid, role, startdate, expirydate 
from  tbl1
where expirydate = Dateadd(day,0, getdate())
```

If I use `<=` or `>=` the above query is working but that is not helpful when we have multiple rows in `tbl1`.

Comment: Far from clear what the issue is here, could you add some actual example data to the question.

Comment: Insert into eprem(Servername, Instancename, Databasename, Environment, userid, 
access, startdate, expirydate, Grantedby, Taskid, [Status], Revokedby)
Select Servername, Instancename, Databasename, Environment, userid, 
access, startdate, expirydate,Grantedby, Taskid, [Status], Revokedby from  eptrack  
where expirydate = Dateadd(day,0, getdate())

This is the original query, when expiry date is today then that row alone should be inserted to a slave table and a trigger will revoke the access as soon as it is inserted. however the row is not getting inserted into the slave table (eprem)

Comment: Huh? Data. One possibility is ExpiryDate has a time component...

Answer (score 2):

It's because `GETDATE()` returns a `DATETIME` value, and you're likely comparing it to a `DATE`, so you're effectively comparing values like this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS DateTimeValue,
       CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) DateValue;
```

**Output:**

```
DateTimeValue            DateValue
2017-10-04 10:34:35.023  2017-10-04
```

By default, a `DATE` will have a time set to midnight if comparing to a `DATETIME`, like: `2017-10-04 00:00:00.000`.

These values aren't going to be equal with a time included, so use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to get a `DATE` without the time:

```
where expirydate = Dateadd(day,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Although, it looks like you don't need that `Dateadd` on the `WHERE` clause, so remove it unless this is edited / sample code. So maybe edit it to this:

```
where expirydate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

**Reference**

[GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql)

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

Comment: CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) worked. Thank you so much.. My activity of automating granting and revoking server roles is complete :).

Comment: @aravind Then can you accept that post as the answer?